# Login loop on xfce4

Tags: arch-linux, xfce

I am running ArchLinux (on a virtual machine) using primarily xfce as graphical environment.

Everything worked fine until I updated some packages using `pacman -Suy`, and after rebooting my system, I am now unable to log in xfce.

Each time I log in, there is a loading time and then the system loops back to the login screen.

Following some advice from many forums and documentations, I have tried to update and remove diverse files from the `.cache/xfce4` directory, then removed all files from `.cache/sessions` which had the effect of removing everything in `.cache/xfce4`, but there was no evolution.

I have also removed the `.ICEauthority` file without any more effect either.

And I have tried updating every packages again with `pacman -Suy` and to remove one by one the `xfce4` packages to install them back, but it did not change anything either.

Fortunately I also have Gnome installed on the same system, and I have no trouble login in with Gnome so I don't understand where this xfce problem comes from...

Answer (score 0):

Create a fail-safe Xorg session which only starts xterm. Login into it, run `xfce4-session`, check the xterm window for errors. E.g.

```
/usr/share/xsessions/safemode.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Safemode (Xterm)
Comment=
Exec=xterm
Terminal=False
TryExec=xterm

[Window Manager]
SessionManaged=true
```

Comment: How do I create a fail-safe Xorg session ? I have tried `sudo startx` and `sudo startxfce4` but both are failing. The Xorg log file indicates `Unable to init server` (and a long backtrace that I don't belive is very helpfull in this context but they just say that an error occured in `/var/lib/Xorg` and `/var/lib/libc.so.6` files)

Comment: I've provided a file you need to create. After creating it, you restart your display manager or reboot.

Comment: I have created the file but I did not have the option to log in safemode

Comment: @ClémentCartier Do you have any other such files under `/usr/share/xsessions/` ? You might have them stored somewhere else. If you have a Wayland login manager you will have them stored elsewhere. Arch Linux docs indicate at least X.org sessions are stored in the same location: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/display_manager#Session_configuration

Comment: Yes I have one file for each graphic manager that I can log in (gnome + xfce) in `/usr/share/xsessions`. Gnome still works, xfce still shows up but still doesn't want to start, but when I added the `safemode.desktop` file in the same place it did not change anything. I have a `/usr/share/wayland-session` with only gnome though. I will try tomorrow to add the `safemode.desktop` there and see if it does something.

Comment: That's weird. Maybe it's down to your display manager because here, and I use LXDM, I can see and use it.